# Neural network training record empty

Tags: matlab, neural-network

My dataset is huge. Let X be input training data which is 6X140000 and T be targets, which are 3X140000.

```
net = patternnet(10);

% Set divide parameters
net.divideFcn = 'divideind';
net.divideParam.trainInd = loc_Train;
net.divideParam.testInd = loc_Test;
net.divideParam.valInd = loc_Valid;

net.trainFcn = 'trainscg';

% Set training parameters
net.trainParam.epochs = 1000;
net.trainParam.max_fail = 20;
net.trainParam.min_grad = 1e-20;
net.trainParam.goal = 1e-10; % Set a very small value

% Set network performance functions
net.performFcn = 'crossentropy';
net.performParam.regularization = 0.02;
net.performParam.normalization = 'none';

net.trainParam.showWindow = 0;
net.trainParam.showCommandLine = 1;
```

After I have setup my network, I run the following code to train my network.

```
[net, tr] = train(net, X,  T);
```

The command line shows:

> Calculation mode: MEX   Training Pattern Recognition Neural Network
>   with TRAINSCG.
>   Epoch 0/1000, Time 0.001, Performance 0.0061672/1e-10,
>   Gradient 0.00065207/1e-20, Validation Checks 0/20
>   Epoch 20/1000, Time 2.214, Performance 0.0060292/1e-10, Gradient 6.3997e-05/1e-20, Validation Checks 20/20
>   Training with TRAINSCG completed: Validation
>   stop.

The tr object, which is the training record, holds information such as testing indices. however, `tr.testInd` returns empty.